# Mybatis custom typehandler getting called twice

Tags: java, xml, spring, mybatis

below is my resultmap.
It calling EncryptedStringTypeHandler twice for each field.
I want only one call per field it works fine If i use constructor inside collection.

```
    <resultMap id="WorkspacePackageDTOMap" type="com.example.dto.WorkspacePackageDTO" autoMapping="true">
    <id column="uid" property="uid" />
    <collection property="participants" ofType="com.example.dto.ParticipantDTO">
        <result column="part_uid" property="uid"/>
        <result column="given_name" property="givenName" typeHandler="com.example.dao.EncryptedStringTypeHandler"/>
        <result column="middle_name" property="middleName"
    typeHandler="com.example.dao.EncryptedStringTypeHandler"/>
        <result column="family_name" property="familyName"
    typeHandler="com.example.dao.EncryptedStringTypeHandler"/>
        <result column="generation_qualifier" property="generationQualifier"/>
        <result column="type" property="type"/>
    </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

Comment: I've seen duplication of handlers due to the `<collection>` not having an `<id>` property and the query returning multiple rows per item in the collection.